# Display random value of text from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
var movie;

var myMovies = ['Bones', 'Psych', 'Big Bang Theory', 'Mad Men', 
'Breaking Bad', 'Modern Family', 'Game of Thrones', 'Dexter','Bones', 'Psych', 'Big Bang Theory', 'Mad Men', 
'Breaking Bad', 'Modern Family', 'Game of Thrones', 'Dexter','Bones', 'Psych', 'Big Bang Theory', 'Mad Men', 
'Breaking Bad', 'Modern Family', 'Game of Thrones', 'Dexter'];

function generateMovies () {
  var movie = myMovies[Math.floor(Math.random() * myMovies.length)];
}


function displayMovie() {
  generateMovies();
  console.log(movie);
  $('body').text(movie);

  setTimeout(function(){
    displayMovie();
},1000);
}

displayMovie();
```

I would like to generate a different movie name and show them on the screen. Seems to be straight forward but obviously not! Seems like may variable is undefined.

Thanks!

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4ggwva4f/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring the variable movie inside the function, so you are not assigning the value to the global variable.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem!

Comment: Yeah, it would help to set the variable that you'll be using. :D

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `var` in your `generateMovies` function.

```
function generateMovies () {
  movie = myMovies[Math.floor(Math.random() * myMovies.length)];
}
```

Basically, you're declaring `movie` first at the start of your script, then again within your `generateMovies` function, so movies is not being returned into your global scope.

Answer (score 0):

As the other guys mentioned, you have a scope problem. Also, you don't really need the global `movie` variable, you could change your code to return the expected value like this:

```
var myMovies = ['Bones', 'Psych', 'Big Bang Theory', 'Mad Men', 
'Breaking Bad', 'Modern Family', 'Game of Thrones', 'Dexter','Bones', 'Psych', 'Big Bang Theory', 'Mad Men', 
'Breaking Bad', 'Modern Family', 'Game of Thrones', 'Dexter','Bones', 'Psych', 'Big Bang Theory', 'Mad Men', 
'Breaking Bad', 'Modern Family', 'Game of Thrones', 'Dexter'];

function generateMovies () {
  return myMovies[Math.floor(Math.random() * myMovies.length)];
}

function displayMovie() {
  var movie = generateMovies();
  console.log(movie);
  $('body').text(movie);

  setTimeout(function(){
    displayMovie();
},1000);
}

displayMovie();
```

Or if you don't really need to do the `console.log` just: `$('body').text(generateMovies())`